# Address alignment in Go

Tags: c, go, x86, simd, avx

So I am using c2go to link C code with Go. The C code requires certain arguments of a function called from Go to be 256 bit aligned (the function arguments are all pointers to Go variables). Is there a way to achieve this is Go (i.e. to specify 256 alignment for a variable in Go)?

In Go, "unsafe.Alignof(f)" shows as 8 bytes aligned (for "var f [8]float32") i.e. the f is guaranteed by Go to be only 8 bytes aligned. I need it to be 32 bytes aligned somehow.

For the curious:
The C code is using SIMD instructions (AVX to be specific). I was using "vmovaps" instruction which requires 256 bit alignment of operands. I can get away with using "vmovups" which doesn't require alignment, but I suspect that has a performance penalty.

Comment: The performance penalty for unaligned loads in AVX is typically negligible (unlike unaligned loads with SSE on older CPUs, 10+ years ago).

Comment: Go guarantees that the minimal alignment property of `var f [8]float32` is `4` not `8`: [Size and alignment guarantees](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Size_and_alignment_guarantees). Also, the output of `var f [8]float32; fmt.Println(unsafe.Alignof(f))` is `4` not `8`: https://play.golang.org/p/ok2IvK0214

Comment: Unaligned loads have extra cost only if you cross a cache-line or page boundary.  It's significant for page-splits (especially on CPUs other than Skylake), and fairly minor for cache-line splits on Haswell and later.  (@PaulR: [splitting unaligned 256b loads into vmovups / vinsertf128 is actually a win on Sandybridge/Ivybridge, *if* the data really is misaligned at runtime](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2011-03/msg01858.html), rather than just not known to be aligned at build time.

Comment: Gcc enables `-mavx256-split-unaligned-load` with `-mtune=generic` even with `-mavx2`, though, because [there's no option to "tune for all CPUs that could run this code"](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80568). :(  This is why it's a really good idea to use `gcc -march=haswell` instead of `gcc -mavx2` if you're building for Haswell.  (clang never does this splitting stuff.)  Also, gcc should probably drop it now, because it's not a big win on SnB, but a big loss on HSW with data that does turn out to be aligned.

Comment: TL:DR: if you can use aligned allocations for all your data, do it.  It doesn't matter if the code you run on it uses instructions that fault on unaligned or handle it in hardware, as long as the data is aligned at runtime.  This is much more important for AVX512 (where vector size = cache-line size, so misaligned means every load crosses a cache-line boundary) than for AVX2.  Being only 16B-aligned or less with AVX2 is usually not a measurable slowdown for looping over an array in memory or L3 cache.  For AVX2, unaligned may only be a problem with data hot in L1D cache, unlike with AVX512.

Answer (score 1):

For example, trading more memory for less CPU time,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

// Float32Align32 returns make([]float32, n) 32-byte aligned.
func Float32Align32(n int) []float32 {
    // align >= size && align%size == 0
    const align = 32 // SIMD AVX byte alignment
    const size = unsafe.Sizeof(float32(0))
    const pad = int(align/size - 1)
    if n <= 0 {
        return nil
    }
    s := make([]float32, n+pad)
    p := uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&s[0]))
    i := int(((p+align-1)/align*align - p) / size)
    j := i + n
    return s[i:j:j]
}

func main() {
    f := Float32Align32(8) // SIMD AVX
    fmt.Printf(
        "SIMD AVX: %T %d %d %p %g\n",
        f, len(f), cap(f), &f[0], f,
    )
    CFuncArg := &f[0]
    fmt.Println("CFuncArg:", CFuncArg)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/mmFnHEwGKt

Output:

```
SIMD AVX: []float32 8 8 0x10436080 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
CFuncArg: 0x10436080
```

Answer (score 0):

The only reasonable way to achieve is to prototype the functions in go and then write the (go) assembly as `BYTE` and `WORD` directives as it's done in golang libraries itself, as outlined in glang-1.9.1 documentation:

> ### Unsupported opcodes
>
> The assemblers are designed to support the compiler so not all
>   hardware instructions are defined for all architectures: if the
>   compiler doesn't generate it, it might not be there. If you need to
>   use a missing instruction, there are two ways to proceed. One is to
>   update the assembler to support that instruction, which is
>   straightforward but only worthwhile if it's likely the instruction
>   will be used again. Instead, for simple one-off cases, it's possible
>   to use the BYTE and WORD directives to lay down explicit data into the
>   instruction stream within a TEXT.

For example,

[blake2b implementation at line 115](https://github.com/golang/crypto/blob/master/blake2b/blake2bAVX2_amd64.s#L115) does this for AVX2